# Colors in legend of heat map plot do not appear

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend, heatmap

I am using R and create the following heat map plot:

```
library(reshape2) 
library(ggplot2) 
require(gridExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
colors <- brewer.pal(9, 'Reds')
sample_data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(36, 36), nrow=6))
sample_data$id<-rownames(sample_data)
sample_data2 <- melt(sample_data, id.var="id")
ggplot(sample_data2, aes(as.factor(variable), as.factor(id), group=id)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(fill = sample_data2$value, label = sample_data2$value), size=3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colors) + 
  labs(x = "variable", y = "id", title="heat map")
```

When I run this code on my Mac, everything is great and the legend appears just fine.

However, when I run it on Windows, the colors of the legend are simply not there, only the numbers. Is there any `ggplot2` command I can use to force the colors to be there in the legend?

Comment: Are you sure? I get an error if I change it.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong about that.  When I run the code on Windows, everything appears to be fine.

Comment: Worked fine for me on Windows (R version 3.1.2, RColorBrewer_1.1-2, ggplot2_1.0.1, reshape2_1.4.1 ).

Comment: I am using RStudio, with R version 3.1.2, RColorBrewer_1.1-2, ggplot2_1.0.0, reshape2_1.4.1.

Comment: @bill999 Works fine for me on Windows http://prntscr.com/6wmj9o

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work for me...

Comment: You might try updating your `ggplot2`

Comment: It also doesn't work in normal R (as opposed to RStudio).

Comment: I saved the file to a pdf and it works perfectly in the pdf.